# Can the Windows Mobile 6 SDK be used to develop programs for older versions of Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'd like to develop a few applications for a device I own which has Windows Mobile 2003 on it, but I don't care to hunt down a copy of Visual Studio 2003 to do so. I'd like to know if the Mobile 6 SDK can be used for this purpose.

There's no upgrade path to newer versions of Windows Mobile for this device, and I doubt I'll be getting any newer devices any time soon. Just in case you'd suggest something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code to the least common denominator.  Using the WimNo 6 SDK is not the route to go as there is no guarantee of backward compatability and you may end up using features available only in the later OS/Platform.  Studio 08 ships with a PPC 2003 SDK, so use that.  The apps developed for PPC 03 should be forward compatible (there are edge cases that migh require additionaly ches in your code, but for the most part they work fine).

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on how you are going to develop this application. If it's just a .NET Compact Framework application you will be fine as long as the right .NET CF version is installed on the device.

If you're going to use C++ and the underlying WinCE API then you would need to make sure that the called functions are supported by WiMo 2003.

Answer (score 0):

You can create programs for WM2003. As long as you can install the .net cf you will be able to run programs compiled under the compact framework. The list of requirements are:
From [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9655156b-356b-4a2c-857c-e62f50ae9a55&displaylang=en):

> **System Requirements**
>    * Supported Operating Systems: Windows CE .NET; Windows Mobile 2003 software for Pocket PCs
>   * Supported Device Operating Systems: Windows Mobile Software for Pocket PC 2003, Windows Mobile 5.0 for PocketPC and Smartphone, Windows CE .NET 5.0 and higher.

Comment: I already have .NET CF 3.5 on the device. However, I don't want to be restricted solely to .NET development. The question is supported device OSes for the SDK and toolchain, not .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll work. I think you need the right SDK, and if that means VS2003, that too.